# Looking For A Reputable And Reliable Windows Registry Search and Replace Tool

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I need to be able to search for registry data referencing my old profile and change it to my new profile. Using regedit works but is obviously slow as there is no replace, only search.

Any recommendations for a reliable tool (VIsta and XP) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you promise to be very careful, you can export part (or all) of the registry from `regedit` to a `.reg` text file, then use your favorite text editor or text-processing tool to do the search and replace then import the resulting `.reg` file back into regedit.

The "Export..." and "Import..." commands are in the "File" menu of the Registry Editor (regedit.exe).

Comment: But then don't you run the risk that something else would have changed while you were messing with the REG file, and then it gets overwritten on re-import?

Comment: That's why when you can you should only export/import the smallest part you need to change. Also, you shouldn't have things running that are actively writing to the registry. Caution should always be used.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.macecraft.com/jv16powertools2009/
Has been recommended to me in the past.

Comment: Yes, i've been using this for years, and its predecessor RegCleaner